# Filtering JSON records - Python

Tags: python, json

I am trying to filter out the records and just show the JSON formatted records based on a specific column value. In this case `displayName`

```
data = {
    "count": 10408,
    "value": [
        {
            "id": 151,
            "name": "Test",
            "url": "https://url",
            "build": {
                "id": "649"
            },
            "isAutomated": true,
            "owner": {
                "displayName": "Test Username",
                "id": "1234"
            },
            "project": {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "Research"
            },
            "startedDate": "2018-06-15T20:57:52.267Z",
            "completedDate": "2018-06-15T20:57:57.813Z",
            "state": "Completed",
            "totalTests": 1,
            "incompleteTests": 0,
            "notApplicableTests": 0,
            "passedTests": 1,
            "unanalyzedTests": 0,
            "revision": 4,
            "webAccessUrl": "https://url",
            "pipelineReference": {
                "pipelineId": 649,
                "stageReference": {},
                "phaseReference": {},
                "jobReference": {}
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 151,
            "name": "Test2",
            "url": "https://url",
            "build": {
                "id": "649"
            },
            "isAutomated": true,
            "owner": {
                "displayName": "Some other User",
                "id": "1234"
            },
            "project": {
                "id": "123",
                "name": "Research"
            },
            "startedDate": "2018-06-15T20:57:52.267Z",
            "completedDate": "2018-06-15T20:57:57.813Z",
            "state": "Completed",
            "totalTests": 1,
            "incompleteTests": 0,
            "notApplicableTests": 0,
            "passedTests": 1,
            "unanalyzedTests": 0,
            "revision": 4,
            "webAccessUrl": "https://url",
            "pipelineReference": {
                "pipelineId": 649,
                "stageReference": {},
                "phaseReference": {},
                "jobReference": {}
            }
        }
        
        ]
}

def filterRecords():
    filtered = [x for x in data if x["value"]["owner"]["displayName"] == "Test Username"]
    print(filtered)

filterRecords()
```

But this is throwing:  `TypeError: string indices must be integers`

Comment: If you iterate over a `dict`, the iteration variable (`x`) will be the key(s) only.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. that makes sense.  I changed it to `filtered = {key:value for (key, value) in data.items() if data["value"]["owner"]["displayName"] == "Test Username"}` but that doesn't seem to help.  Same error

Comment: The problem now is that data["value"] is a list of dictionaries which needs an integer to select the entry you want, not a string like "owner".

Comment: I suspect what you are really wanting to do is to iterate over the entries in data["value"].  So you want something like
`filtered = [x for x in data["value"] if x["owner"]['displayName"] == "Test Username"]`

Comment: Yes, thank you.  The endgame is to export this to csv or excel, so I needed to filter the massive dataset first beforehand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`value` is a list not a dict. Since you want to iterate over the list, not the data object, you'll want to scope down to `value` for your *iterable*.

`filtered = [x for x in data["value"] if x["owner"]["displayName"] == "Test Username"]`